# React function binding is not working on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have code:

```
var React = require('react');

class MasterLayout extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("I am constructor");
        this.getComponent = this.getComponent.bind(this);
        this.testMethod = this.test.bind(this);
        this.testMethod();
    }

    test() {
        console.log("test method called");
    }

    getComponent(ev) {
        console.log('li item clicked!');
        event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3 id={this.props.id} onClick={this.getComponent}>qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq</h3>
            </div>

        )
    }
};

module.exports = MasterLayout;
```

When I run node server and go to localhost page, page is rendered sucesfully without any errors.

After click on h3 element nothing happens.

When is pagge loaded i am getting in console:

```
I am constructor
test method called
```

After click on h3, nothing happens. Whats wrong is with my code?

EDIT:

`onclick="console.log('The link was clicked.'); return false">` too NOT working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3 id={this.props.id} onClick={this.onClick}>CLICK ME</h3>
```

Unless I'm missing something you don't have an `onClick` method in `MasterLayout`

Are you sure you don't mean to create an `onHeaderClicked` (example) method in `MasterLayout`, bind it in the constructor, and use that instead of `this.onClick`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your test() method to be named onClick():

```
var React = require('react');

class MasterLayout extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("I am constructor");
        this.getComponent = this.getComponent.bind(this);
        this.testMethod = this.test.bind(this);
        this.testMethod();
    }

    onClick() {
        console.log("test method called");
    }

    getComponent(ev) {
        console.log('li item clicked!');
        event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
    }




    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3 id={this.props.id} onClick={this.onClick}>CLICK ME</h3>
            </div>

        )
    }
};

module.exports = MasterLayout;
```

or if you are trying to invoke the getComponent() method change it in your render code to use that:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
        <h3 id={this.props.id} onClick={this.getComponent}>CLICK ME</h3>
    </div>

  )
}
```

Or if you want to invoke both, call the 2nd method in the first method call function block:

```
getComponent(ev) {
  console.log('li item clicked!');
  event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
  this.onClick();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, this not help me. Still not working.

Comment: Maybe you need to rename your code in the constructor? this.testMethod = this.test.bind(this); this.testMethod();  this.testMethod method doesn't exist in your class

Comment: `<h3 id={this.props.id} onClick={this.getComponent}>qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq</h3>` too not working

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens when you click on `h3` because after you click you will get an error that `cannot read property currentTarget of undefined` as you are receiving the event parameter as `ev` and using it as `event`

You need to modify your getComponent method to

```
getComponent(ev) {
    console.log('li item clicked!');
    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
}
```

Comment: getComponent(ev)  is no called.

Comment: Are you sure you have `onClick` and not `onclick`